# The length of UserName of Table UserProfile

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

The following shows the code of the automatically generated class `UserProfile` when creating a new Asp.Net MVC 4 web application. The column of table `UserProfile` will have the type of `nvarchar(56) not null`. However, it doesn't have the attribute of `MaxLength(56)` and `Required`? Why it has the length of 56 and nullibility of `not null`?

I will need to add an email property to the class and using migration to update the table. Should I add attribute `[Required, MaxLength(256)] string Email`?

```
[Table("UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What happens when you do it? That's one good way to find out :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes, go ahead and add the needed attributes. Further read about Data Annotations [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg193958.aspx)

Plus the UserName field is hardly more than 56 characters. For example, adil.mughal is a user name and I am not sure how exactly 56 number is identified in membership API but it's most likely enough for the need.